# System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid

Tags: vb.net-2010

Dim day As String = Label22.Text
Dim week As String = DateTime.ParseExact(day, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DayOfWeek.ToString
Label88.Text = week

more things but nothing

Answer (score 0):

You forgot parenthesis after ToString method call :)
Each method call must contain the parameter list in parenthesis - even if the parameter list is empty.

Should be:

```
Dim day As String = Label22.Text 
Dim week As String = DateTime.ParseExact(day, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DayOfWeek.ToString() 
Rem --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^ here!

Label88.Text = week
```